# A fibre bundle of n-tuples of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

The question is: does the surjective, multilinear map $\pi: (\mathbb R^\infty)^n\to \Lambda^n(\mathbb R^\infty)$ defined by $(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\mapsto v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_n,$ define a fibre bundle? This would make geometric statements about linearly independent vectors.